# Code not printing the events in tkinter python

Tags: python, events, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a code that prints the events/actions that happens on the tkinter area. When I run the script I don't get an error but when I'm clicking on the graphics area nothing prints out.

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=640, height=480)
canvas.pack()
def function1(event):
    print(repr(event))
canvas.bind("ButtonPress-1", function1)
canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: it has to be `<ButtonPress-1>` - you forgot `< >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the instance of `tkinter.Tk()` and use it as root. The following implementation works for me as expected:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
def function1(event):
    print(repr(event))

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=640, height=480)
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", function1)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works I didn't know I have to put the "<>" there. By the way, it even works without the root (at least for me).

Comment: _"You need to define the instance of tkinter.Tk()"_ - that is not the issue. It's a best practice, but it has nothing to do with this problem. The issue is a bad event specification (`ButtonPress-1` vs `<ButtonPress-1>`)